# Inherit bootstrap properties to a custom class

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, sass, django-packages

I want my custom class `pm_btn` to get all the properties that bootstrap's `btn` class has. One way is to use the actual source code of the `btn` class. But I believe that there has to be a better way. Therefore, I tried a bit of `scss`, where **inheriting** properties is quite easy and trivial using `@extend` as follows:

```
.pm_btn{
    @extends .btn;
}
```

But this throws error :

```
Error: The target selector was not found.
Use "@extend .btn !optional" to avoid this error.
```

I am **trying to achieve**: apply bootstrap like classes to `django-postman` classes.
Please suggest me how can I achieve this, if I am on the right track by choosing `SCSS` or should I think in some other directions. Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: One way I can think of is to add the desired classes using JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your tooling setup is, but if it will allow it, [Bootstrap has a Sass version](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/) you can use. This will allow you to extend bootstrap's functionality with your own custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap sass files and @extends keyword to extend .btn class to your needs
or
more easily you can write a separate class along and modify its properties to suit your needs and you can call that style for reusability , For eg

```css
.button--custom {
  /* required properties here */
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary text-light button--custom">my button</button>
```

You need to call in the given class  order or it wont work

Comment: You are modifying the markup for ```button``` element. The crux is, I don't have access to the ```<button class=".....">```. It is given that button will have ```<button class="pm_btn">``` and I want to use this ```.pm_btn```  to inherit the properties of bootstrap's ```btn btn-primary```. I am ***not*** allowed to insert classes into my markup for ```<button>```. If I had that option then it would have been trivial.